# jquery ajax get data and set to global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the beginning of my JS script I want assign some global variables from a php file which I need to use allover the page in different functions. So, first I did like this:

HTML

```
<button onclick="somename()"> CALL FUNCTION </button></div>
```

JS

```
var a,
    b;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {getvar: "getvar"},
    success: function(data) {
        a = data["a"];
        b = data["b"];
    },
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
}); 

    console.log(a);
$(document).ready(function() {  
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
});

function somename() {
    console.log(a);
}
```

For the above way I need to use async: false, but this is already deprecated and not good solution because the browser can freeze but it works as needed. Then, I changed to this way:

```
$.post(
    "test.php",
    {getvar: "getvar"},
    function(data) {
        funget(data);       
    },
    "json"
);  

function funget(param) {
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        console.log(param["a"]);
        console.log(param["b"]);
    });

    function somename() {
        console.log(param["a"]);
    }
}
```

but having the whole js script in one function doesn't seem to be a good solution as well, at least the function somename() will not work there can be some other problems. So, what to do to get things working as needed and have save solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) or  to wait for the ajax call to complete before moving on.

```
var a,
b;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {getvar: "getvar"},
    success: function(data) {
        a = data["a"];
        b = data["b"];
    },
    dataType: "json"
}); 

// do "asynchronous" things here

$.ajaxComplete(function() {
   // do stuff now that call is complete
});
```

Another method is to use the ajax method's complete property.

```
var a,
b;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {getvar: "getvar"},
    success: function(data) {
        a = data["a"];
        b = data["b"];
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        // do stuff now that call is complete
    },
    dataType: "json"
}); 

// do "asynchronous" things here
```

Comment: What should I do referring to my example? Do I put everything inside `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { });` except `function somename()`? Is that save for jq functions inside  `$(document).ready(function() { });`?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. You can display part of the page immediately, then on complete, display the rest of the page and call functions to fill in data. Put anything that will break without the ajax call being complete inside the ajaxComplete().

Comment: what about other ajax calls in the script, how to separate that this ajaxComplete should refer only to this one in the example?

Comment: Thank you for reply. It seems that the second method is working fine in my real code (with the first one I had some problems with my website because of other ajax calls). So, I've put the entire content also with the function name `$(document).ready(function() { });` into the complete section. I need more testing, but so far it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
// we put a and b in global scope
var a, b;

// we delay ready event
$.holdReady( true );

$.post(
    "test.php",
    {getvar: "getvar"},
    function(data) {
        funget(data);       
    },
    "json"
);  

var funget = function(param) {
    // since defined in global scopes, we will be able to access them from everywhere
    a = param["a"];
    b = param["b"];

    // we release ready event
    $.holdReady( false );
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/

I used something close to your example for better understanding. But, it's true that a complete callback on the ajax request is simpler. holdReady suggests a bad design actually in this case.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll check your method if my tests will fail with the ajax complete one.

Comment: actually, I didn't see you were looking for delaying the ready event, I made some quick changes to fit with this. The other answer seems, nevertheless, the way to go for me.